Custom angular directive is not working in WebStorm IDE. Expression expected in ngFor angular
I've created a custom directive called ngForFlTrackByIndex to be used inside ngFor. Everything is fine in vscode but in WebStorm complains Expression expected.

Also the directive code:
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngForFlTrackByIndex]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class TrackByIndexDirective<T> {
  constructor(@Host() private readonly _ngFor: NgForOf<T>) {
    this._ngFor.ngForTrackBy = (index: number): number => index;
  }
}

Any idea?

@Cuzy, indeed, the code compiles successfully; however, the logs are quite noisy. I've already tried restarting and clearing the cache, but there hasn't been much improvement in the situation.

Why not apply the directive the conventional way? Also, if you used the new control flow – you wouldn't need this directive at all I guess. Just track $index. WebStorm problems cannot be solved on stackoverflow. Please file a bug report  to the devs of the IDE https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

@Sergey The control_flow is still in developer preview. So would wait to be stable before using it.

It's stable since v18 that will be released very soon. AFAIK nothing changed and the preview was just for the toolings to adapt to the new syntax

I am able to get rid of this error, by using an input parameter, but note, that when we pass the input as undefined, we can get rid of this error and make it track by index! if not it will track by value.
DIRECTIVE:
import {Directive, Host, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {NgForOf} from "@angular/common";

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngForFlTrackByIndex]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class TrackByIndexDirective {
  private prop: string | undefined;

  constructor(@Host() private readonly _ngFor: NgForOf<any>) {
    this._ngFor.ngForTrackBy = (index: number, item: any): number => this.prop ? item[this.prop] : index;
  }

  @Input("ngForFlTrackByIndex")
  public set propertyName(value: string | undefined) {
    this.prop = value || "";
  }
}

HTML:
<div *ngFor='let task of tasks;let i = index;flTrackByIndex: undefined'> <!-- track by index  -->
  asdf
</div>
<div *ngFor='let task of tasks;let i = index;flTrackByIndex: "id"'> <!-- track by value (optional!) -->
  asdf
</div>

TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import {TrackByIndexDirective} from "../directive";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, TrackByIndexDirective, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  tasks = [
    {id: 1, name: 'test1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'test2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'test3'},
    {id: 4, name: 'test4'},
    {id: 5, name: 'test5'}
  ]
  title = 'untitled';
}


Thank you for the answer. However, sending an unnecessary 'undefined' value isn't a good idea. Our company has 40 developers using various IDEs, such as VSCode and others, and we don't want to disrupt their workflow.

@AlirezaAhmadi Ignore this error and proceed forward, this is an insignificant error to wrack your brain over!
